# Magento2: Mirasvit SearchAutocomplete not working with Elasticsearch search engine

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, elasticsearch, mirasvit

I am facing an issue with Mirasvit SearchAutocomplete Module.

It's working properly with **mysql** search engine. And it stops working with the Elasticsearch6+ search engine.

Facing this error:  `Sorry, something went wrong. You can find out more in the error log` in ajax response.

I have debug the code, it seems collection not working properly after activating the Elasticsearch search engine.

Have you guys faced such kind of issue?

Comment: Have you checked error log?

Comment: Yes, I found the same error there.  "Sorry, something went wrong. You can find out more in the error log"

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign **Search Engine** to **Elasticsearch Engine** which is compatible with ES 6.
[image]

**[Update]**

Open **vendor/mirasvit/module-search/src/Search/etc/di.xml** and check the ES engine.

```
<type name="Magento\Search\Model\Adminhtml\System\Config\Source\Engine">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="engines" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="mysql" xsi:type="string">Magento Native MySQL Engine</item>
            <item name="elasticsearch" xsi:type="string">Magento Native Elasticsearch 2+</item>
            <item name="elasticsearch5" xsi:type="string">Magento Native Elasticsearch 5+</item>
            <item name="elasticsearch6" xsi:type="string">Magento Native Elasticsearch 6+</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

**elasticsearch** is for Mirasvit

Comment: Thank you so much @Sohel for the response but in my version 2.3.4 there are only 4 options.
MySQL, 
Elasticsearch, 
Elasticsearch 5.0+, 
Elasticsearch 6.0+

Comment: What is your magento version?

Comment: It's Magento 2.3.4

Comment: Something wrong with your installation then. Check updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have to debug more for this..